# Message class, with constructors for data from user and from database

Tags: beginner, constructor, kotlin

I'm fairly new to Kotlin, and am looking to slim down a data class.

It has two constructors, one for creation based on user input, and one for creation based on database data.

```
open class Message : Unique {

    val timestamp: Long
    val contents: String

    constructor(contents: String) : super() {
        validateMessageContents(contents)
        this.contents = contents
        this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    constructor(id: String, contents: String, timestamp: Long) : super(id) {
        validateMessageContents(contents)
        this.contents = contents
        this.timestamp = timestamp
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 1024

        private fun validateMessageContents(contents: String) {
            if (contents.isEmpty()) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Contents cannot be blank/empty")
            }
            if (contents.length > MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Message too long - please limit to $MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH characters.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Unique` superclass has a single `id: String` property, but will generate a random UUID if the default constructor is called.

I'm wondering - how can I slim down this class? I've fiddled with trying to add a primary constructor, turn it into a data class, but each route I've hit a hurdle.

The things that stick out:

1. I'm calling `validateMessageContents()` in both constructors, but can't move it to `init` because the `contents` isn't yet available.
2. The second constructor, aside from validating the contents, is just two ugly assignment statements.
3. The two codepaths to either `super()` *or* `super(id)` make it difficult for one of these constructors to be made primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's address your primary concern: the two constructors.

If the code to generate the UUID is not overly complicated, we can extract it and use it in our constructor as a default value (I don't like this because it adds code redundancy but I guess this is the only way to consolidate both constructors).
The same applies to the `timestamp`.
Thus we can use a primary constructor with the more specific super-constructor.

```
open class Message(
    id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    val contents: String,
    val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
) : Unique(id) {
```

Here we combined both constructors and kept the order of the parameters.
Now we can use the `init`-block as well to validate the contents of the message:

```
init {
    validateMessageContents(contents)
}
```

That's the majority of things one can do to slim the class down.

Keep in mind that you need to specify a named parameter `contents` now because the first positional parameter `id` has a default value.

```
Message(contents = "test")
```

Another thing to do is to annotate your functions according to their behavior, so annotate `validateMessageContents` with `@Throws`.
I've also taken this opportunity to convert the two `if`-statements to a `when`-block. It's functionally the same (a string can't be empty and 1024 characters long at the same time).

```
@Throws(IllegalArgumentException::class)
    private fun validateMessageContents(contents: String) {
        when {
            contents.isEmpty() -> {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Contents cannot be blank/empty")
            }
            contents.length > MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH -> {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Message too long - please limit to $MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH characters.")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`require`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) to reduce your validations:

   ```
   require(contents.isNotEmpty()) { "Contents cannot be blank/empty" }
   require(contents.length > MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
       "Message too long - please limit to $MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH characters."
   }
   ```
2. In my opinion, the main factor in preventing you from having a clean primary constructor is indeed the two paths to the super class (via `super()` or `super(id)`) and having a super class define the `id` property is in fact what also prevents you from making this a data class. I recommend making `Unique` an `interface` or `abstract class` with no properties in its constructor. e.g.:

   ```
   interface Unique {
       val id: String
   }

   fun randomId() = "${UUID.randomUUID()}"

   data class Message(
           override val id: String, 
           val contents: String, 
           val timestamp: Long
   ) : Unique {
       init {
           require(contents.isNotEmpty()) { "Contents cannot be blank/empty" }
           require(contents.length > MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
               "Message too long - please limit to $MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH characters."
           }
       }

       constructor(contents: String) : this(
               id = randomId(),
               contents = contents,
               timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
       )

       companion object {
           const val MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 1024
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Right, the two-path-problem seems significant here. I made it a superclass because I have ~12 model classes that inherit from it, and I wanted their ID assignment, whether it's from the DB or from a random UUID, to not be duplicated. Not to mention, it's included in the `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations as well.

Comment: Don't you need to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations in each concrete model class anyway though?

Comment: Yes, but they can defer the `id` comparison, or _whatever it is that makes them Unique_ to the superclass. I use `EqualsBuilder`, and am calling `appendSuper(super.equals(other))`.

Comment: Very good. Personally I think I would prefer using `data class` which means you have to make `id`, etc. `abstract` but I also understand the desire to not duplicate code, etc. Without seeing the full model I may be completely off here but you might consider looking into using composition instead of inheritance (Effective Java Item 16). e.g. You would have a generic `Entity<T>` class with `id`, `timestamp`, and whatever else is common across all of your entities and then use something like `data: T` for your specific data: `e: Entity<Message>` would have `e.id`, `e.timestamp`, `e.data.contents`

Answer (score 0):

I only know Koltin in passing, but would it be an option to make the `id` parameter of the constructor nullable? That way you'd only have one code path, however you may would have to use `null` during construction.

Combined with GiantTree's suggestion, something like this:

```
open class Unique(optionalId: String? = null) {
    val id: String = if (optionalId == null) createId() else optionalId

    companion object {
        fun createId() = "Generated"
    }
}

open class Message(id: String? = null, contents: String, timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()) : Unique(id) {

    init {
        validateMessageContents(contents)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 1024

        private fun validateMessageContents(contents: String) {
           // ...
        }
    }
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val m1 = Unique()
    val m2 = Unique("id1")

    val m3 = Message(null, "abc", 1) // or
    val m4 = Message(contents = "abc", timestamp = 1)

    val m5 = Message("id2", "xyz", 2)

    println(m1.id)
    println(m2.id)
    println(m3.id)
    println(m4.id)
    println(m5.id)
}
```